# outer function error: Error in outer function

Tags: r

I need to draw a perspective plot for a homework problem. My function uses two vectors x_dartbrd, y_dartbrd and does a bunch of operations to return another vector of the same length as the arguments. Now when I am trying to run the outer function to generate the z's for the perspective plot it is giving me the following error:

```
Error in outer(x_dartbrd, y_dartbrd, function(x_dartbrd, y_dartbrd) mapply("DartBoard",  : 
  dims [product 10201] do not match the length of object [1030301]
.
```

My code is as below:

```
x_dartbrd = linspace(-170,170,101) #vector of 1st argument
y_dartbrd = linspace(-170,170,101) #vector of 2nd argument
DartBoard = function(x_dartbrd,y_dartbrd)
{
Some specific operations as per the problem
return(Score) #Score is of the same length as 1st and 2nd arguments
}
z <- outer(x_dartbrd, y_dartbrd,function(x_dartbrd,y_dartbrd)mapply("DartBoard",x_dartbrd,y_dartbrd))
```

This outer function just does not seem to be working.
Appreciate all your suggestions on this.

Comment: Have you tried `outer(x_dartbrd, y_dartbrd, FUN = DartBoard)`?

Comment: Hi Flodel, I tried it but the same error is showing up again! :(

Comment: You should state that `linspace` is from `pracma` (assuming that's the one you're using).  But clearly if `Dartboard` is returning a vector of length same as its input , then what happens if the inputs are of different length? See what your `mapply` is returning (most likely  a list with an, er..., interesting collection of lengths).

Comment: Hi Carl, Yes I am using linspace from pracma. Ideally I was expecting the outer function to give me 101 *101 = 10201 dimension, but for some reason this is multiplying by another 101, so the length is becoming 1030301 which is where the program is erroring out

Comment: Yes, and I'm pretty sure it's because you should **not** be using `mapply` in there.